# How to solve this statistics problem using binomial coefficient?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

I thought of a problem today. There are 100 names in a bucket. Your name is in the bucket. If I *randomly* draw 5 names, without replacement, what is the probability that your name will be drawn?

I can solve the problem without binomial coefficient (n choose k).

Let P(A) be the probability that your name will be drawn and let P(B) be the probability that your name *will not* drawn.

$$ P(B) = \frac{99}{100}*\frac{98}{99}*\frac{97}{98}*\frac{96}{97}*\frac{95}{96} = 0.95$$

$$ P(A) = 1 - P(B) = 0.05 $$

I then tried to figure out the answer using binomial coefficient.

$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{100!}{5!(95!)} = 75287520 $

Since the answer I got was .05, that must mean there are 75287520 * .05 = 3764376 groups of 5 names that include your name. The problem is, I do not know how to get that number besides writing down all the combinations. How to get the number 3764376 is what I'd like to know.

Comment: You have got two answers that address your concern, but why not just compute $P(A) = \frac5{100}$ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find a group that includes your name,  choose the 4 *other* members of that group among the 99 people who are not you.

$$ \binom{99}{4} = 3,764,376 $$

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It makes me feel bad that I didn't get something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

another way to find how many groups of $5$ elements contain $a$ is to do:

$\binom{100}{5}-\binom{99}{5}$.

Comment: The fact that our two answers coincide is the pascal recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_{1},A_{2},A_{3},A_{4},A_{5}$ be the events that you name is on the first, second, third, fourth or fifth slips.

$\begin{align}
P(A_{1}\cup{A_{2}}\ldots{A_{5}})&=P(A_{1})+\ldots+P(A_{5})\text{ ; since these are disjoint}\\
&=\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{100}\\
&=\frac{5}{100}
\end{align}$

We can just as well think of first choosing five random slips out of $100$ blank slips and then randomly write names on the slips, which gives a $5/100$ chance that your name is on one of those five chosen slips.